# drawtext doesn't work in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, drawtext

i m working on a project that consist on creating an uml tool with qt and for now i have a problem with drawingtext on an arrow so this is my code :

```
void Arrow::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * ,QWidget *)
{
    if (myStartItem->collidesWithItem(myEndItem))
        return;

    QPen myPen = pen();
    myPen.setColor(myColor);
    qreal arrowSize = 20;
    painter->setPen(myPen);
    painter->setBrush(myColor);

    QLineF centerLine(myStartItem->pos(), myEndItem->pos());
    QPolygonF endPolygon = myEndItem->polygon();
    QPointF p1 = endPolygon.first() + myEndItem->pos();
    QPointF p2;
    QPointF intersectPoint;
    QLineF polyLine;
    for (int i = 1; i < endPolygon.count(); ++i)
    {
        p2 = endPolygon.at(i) + myEndItem->pos();
        polyLine = QLineF(p1, p2);
        QLineF::IntersectType intersectType =
            polyLine.intersect(centerLine, &intersectPoint);
        if (intersectType == QLineF::BoundedIntersection)
            break;
        p1 = p2;
    }

    setLine(QLineF(intersectPoint, myStartItem->pos()));

    double angle = ::acos(line().dx() / line().length());
    if (line().dy() >= 0)
        angle = (Pi * 2) - angle;

    QPointF arrowP1 = line().p1() + QPointF(sin(angle + Pi / 3) * arrowSize,
                                            cos(angle + Pi / 3) * arrowSize);
    QPointF arrowP2 = line().p1() + QPointF(sin(angle + Pi - Pi / 3) * arrowSize,
                                            cos(angle + Pi - Pi / 3) * arrowSize);

    arrowHead.clear();
    arrowHead << line().p1() << arrowP1 << arrowP2;
    painter->drawLine(line());
    //painter->drawPolygon(arrowHead);
    if (isSelected())
    {
        painter->setPen(QPen(myColor, 1, Qt::DashLine));
        QLineF myLine = line();
        myLine.translate(0, 4.0);
        painter->drawLine(myLine);
        myLine.translate(0,-8.0);
        painter->drawLine(myLine);
        QPoint point = QPoint( 10, 20 );
        painter->drawText( point, "You can draw text from a point..." );
    }
}
```

and nothing happens i can draw the arrow but the text does not appear on the arrow what should i do ? please i need some help

Comment: The `isSelected()` check look suspicious. Tip 1: indent your code. Tip 2: indent your code. Tip 3: it can really help to use indentation.

Comment: `isSelected()` - what is return value? Did you try debugger?

Comment: Many editors will automatically indent your code for you. If you don't have such an editor, you can use the free AStyle tool to fix up your existing code. Then just keep it properly indented.

Comment: Hi, i didn't check in details the code but it seems like you only use one color. Writing black on black is often hard to see.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you did that wrong.

You should compose your graphics item using `QGraphicsPathItem`, `QGraphicsPolygonItem`, `QGraphicsRectItem`, and `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` instead drawing everything yourself.
Just provide some root item responsible for managing children (lines text and polygons). It will be easier to do this properly.

Secondly your paint method is faulty. You should restore initial state of the painter!

And finally I'm pretty sure your problem is caused by incorrect implementation of `boundingRect`. It is quite common mistake when performing such complex drawing in paint method.